# Estimator of ratio of central moments

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, estimators

In the context of *Control Variates* one has to estimate, for example,  the following ratios of central moments:

$$\frac{\mu_{1,1}}{\mu_{0,2}} \quad \text{and} \quad  \frac{\mu_{1,1}^2}{\mu_{0,2}}$$

with,
$$\mu_{p,q} = E[(X- \bar{X})^p(Y-\bar{Y})^q]$$

I know that it is possible to have an unbiased estimator of $\mu_{1,1}$, $\mu_{0,2}$ and even $\mu_{1,1}^2$ **for any distribution**.

Now, will the ratio of the unbiased estimators be biased? I guess it will be (I've done some numerical examples), but I would like some confirmation.

Is it possible to have an unbiased estimator of the ratio of central moments as it is the case with the product? (One can have an unbiased estimator of, say $\mu_{2,0}\mu_{0,2}$, and in general of any product of central moments, for any distribution.). If anyone has a bibliographical reference that I could read on this topic, that would be great!

Disclaimer: It is not my intention to use an unbiased estimator. I just want to know if it is possible to have one.

Comment: 1. More correctly, it is possible to find an unbiased estimator of any central moment, provided the relevant raw moments exist. 2. Since you are dividing by the variance, would it perhaps help to standardise your distribution, such that the variance would then be 1, and your ratio then becomes the problem of finding an unbiased estimator of the covariance (or of squared covariance).

Comment: @wolfies Hi! Thank you! uh... I believe I can't standardize since the random variables X and Y come from black box functions that take random parameters as input; so I don't know the true value of their variances. I'm looking for a confirmation (bibliographical reference) to the following: "In general, you can't have an unbiased estimator of the ratio" or "In general, it is possible to have an unbiased estimator of the ratio, but it is too difficult"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"will the ratio of the unbiased estimators be biased?"

Yes, it is biased, but it is unbiased asymptotically.

"Is it possible to have an unbiased estimator of the ratio of central moments as it is the case with the product?"

Depend on if it is possible to derive the distribution of converted statistics, and the expectation of the converted statistics. If you can get the expectation of the converted statistics, the adding some modification to the original converted statistics can correct the bias to zero.

In practice, by using Taylor series, the bias can be reduced a lot.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! "Yes, it is biased, but it is unbiased asymptotically." Do you have any bibliographic reference where it's explained?

Comment: It is very common, so it's hard to find ref. Here is one, Maybe you can find something from its list of ref. Box, M. J. “Bias in Nonlinear Estimation.” Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), vol. 33, no. 2, 1971, pp. 171–201. JSTOR, JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/2985002.

Comment: Hi! That's very helpful. Section 6 of that paper pretty much sums it up. Thanks!